# mvc html.actionlink css class

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

Cant seem to get a class to over write the inherited styles for a:link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { @class = "htmlactionlink" })
```

CSS

```
a:link, a:visited,
a:active, a:hover 
{
    color: #333;
}

.htmlactionlink {
    color: red;
}
```

Doesn't effect the style of the  element?

If I apply a inline style, it works.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in understanding the CSS: [6.4.3 Calculating a selector's specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity). Small Extract

A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:

1. count 1 if the declaration is from is a 'style' attribute ..
2. count the number of ID attributes in the selector (= b)
3. count the number of other attributes and **pseudo-classes** in the selector (= c)
4. count the number of element names and pseudo-elements in the selector (= d)

Other words:

1. inline declaration style=""
2. #myId {}
3. .htmlactionlink {}
4. a {}

The point 3. says, that the same value for precedense is applied to class and pseudo-class [(see more in w3schools.com)](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

It means, that calculation for

```
a:link is { a=0, b=0, c=1, d=1}
```

while

```
.htmlactionlink is { a=0, b=0, c=1, d=0}
```

And that's why the `a:link` statement takes the precedence, because it takes 1 point for class and one for element name.

NOTE:

from my perspective the most correct solution is the

```
.htmlactionlink:link, .htmlactionlink:visited ... {
    color: red;
}
```

In that case, we do get {**c=2**, d=0}, we do not count on the order as with a simple `A.htmlactionlink` *{c=1, d=1}*

Answer (score 0):

try

```
a:link, a:visited,
a:active, a:hover 
{
    color: #333;
}

a.htmlactionlink 
{
    color: red;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dXzNK/1/)**